# http redirect to https works only at root level

Tags: .htaccess

I have a rather simple question but haven't found the answer.
I have set up an http redirection to https in my htaccess. I works fine on my root domain

```
http://exemple.com -> https://exemple.com
```

but does not work on all other pages :

```
http://example.com/page1 -> http://example.com/page1
http://example.com/blog/page2 -> http://example.com/blog/page2
```

I have configured my .htaccess as is :

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exemple.com
```

Comment: You have only conditions in your htaccess file? There is no rules I see in it. If its not full htaccess then kindly do update it in your question, thank you.

Comment: actually I had multiple old htaccess files, wordpress seem to automatically regenerate htaccess (due to a plugin), I added the lines Telinov proposed and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet tells to check if current connection is HTTPS, and then rewrites the HTTP_HOST, it has nothing to do with HTTP->HTTPS redirection.

Usually to do that you can find multiple examples online, for example this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: wordpress has rewritten my htaccess removing those lines I added years ago. I put them back and it worked thanks